complement of smooth submanifold is simply-connected
I have problem when solving this problem: Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth submanifold of dimension $m < n − 2.$ Prove that the
complement  $\mathbb{R}^n -M $ is connected and simply-connected.
I consider one-point compactification and view $M$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb{S}^n$. But I don't sure if $M$ is a closed subset of  $\mathbb{S}^n$ and if it will help calculating $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^n -M )$.And I don't how to use smoothness of $M$.

Of course $M$ does not have to be closed subset of $\mathbb{S}^n$, even if it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For simple connectedness, i think the idea is to represent a loop via a smooth map from $S^1$ to your complement, then (smoothly) extend to a disk (as a map into $\mathbb{R}^n$), then (smoothly) homotope this map to be transverse to $M$.

I will prove the statement using some theorems on transversality.
$\textbf{Connecteness:}$ Let $x,y$ be two points in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus M$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected there is a smooth map $\gamma :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\gamma(0)=x, \gamma(1)=y$. Here we are treating $[0,1]$ as a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial I = \{0,1\}$. Note that the map $$\partial \gamma: \{0,1\}\to \mathbb{R}^n$$ is smooth and $\partial \gamma (\partial I)\cap M = \emptyset$. So the intersection is transversal in other language $\partial \gamma \pitchfork M$. Now we will use the following result from Guillemin and Pollack [Page 73, corollary], to get a smooth map $\tilde{\gamma}:I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\tilde{\gamma} \pitchfork M$ and $\partial \gamma = \partial \tilde{\gamma}$.
$\textbf{Corllorary from GP:}$ If, for $f: X \to Y$, the boundary map $\partial f: \partial X \to Y$ is transversal to $Z$, then there exists a map $g: X \to Y$ homotopic to $f$ such that $\partial g = \partial f$  and $g \pitchfork Z$.
Now since, $\tilde{\gamma}\pitchfork M$ we must have $\tilde{\gamma}(I)\cap M = \emptyset$ otherwise $f^{-1}(M)$ will be a regular manifold of $I$ of codimesnion $\text{codim}_{\mathbb{R}^n} M$ which is $>2$ (from the given condition). But it's not possible. So, image of $\tilde{\gamma}$  lies in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M$.
$\textbf{Simply conncetdness:}$  Since the space is path-connected we don't need to bother about the choice of the base point. Let, $f:S^1\to \mathbb{R}^n\setminus M$ be a loop. We can view this as a loop in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected so there is a homotopy $F: S^1\times I \to \mathbb{R^n}$ so that, $F(t,1) = f(1)$ and $F(t,0)=f(t)$. (Here all these maps are assumed to be smooth).
Note that $\partial F: \partial(S^1\times I) \to \mathbb{R^n}$ has image $f(1)\cup f(S^1)$ which do not intersect with $M$, i.e it's tarnsversal. So by the previous corollary there is $G: S^1 \times I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $G \pitchfork M$ and $\partial G = \partial F$. If $G(S^1 \times I) \cap M$ is not empty then $G^{-1}(M)$ must be a non-empty regular submanifold of $S^1 \times I$ with codimension $\text{codim}_{\mathbb{R}^n} M>2$. But it's not possible. So, $G: S^1\times I\to \mathbb{R}^n\setminus M$ is a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map at $f(1)$.
$\textbf{Remark}:$ For the connected-ness argument we needed $m < n-1$ but for simply-connectedness we have strictly used $m<n-2$. Note that, all the maps above are smooth. Although the loops are meant to be continuous maps only, we can also use smooth loops for smooth structures.

I think you need to argue either that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M$ is a smooth manifold (so you can take $f$ smooth as you said), or that when smoothing such a loop in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you don't change the homotopy class in the complement.

@SteveD I am sorry but I don't understand why do we need to prove such thing? Can you please elaborate?  Thank you!

If you don't know the complement is smooth, then how can you say you can take $f:S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\setminus M$ smooth, as you said in your final remark?

Ohh! Now I get it. By this I mean a smooth loop $f:S^1\to R^n$ and the image lie inside $R^n \setminus M$.
